# Swift 4 - How to have a function set a variable outside that function

Tags: swift, function, variables

So I just started with Swift the other day. In messing around with some code, I tried to write a function that would have a target player attack and enemy and have that enemies HP reduced by the amount of attack power of the player. Everything works inside the function fine, but I can't seem to find a way to get it to effect the selected enemy outside the function. Maybe its something that will come in a later lesson, but in my head it should be something simple that I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
struct Player {
    var maxHP: Int
    var currentHP: Int
    var maxMP: Int
    var currentMP: Int
    var currentLVL: Int
    var damageATT: Int
}

struct Enemy {
    var maxHP: Int
    var currentHP: Int
    var damageAtt: Int
}

var alexRider = Player(maxHP: 100, currentHP: 100, maxMP: 100, currentMP: 100, currentLVL: 1, damageATT: 5)
var enemyOne = Enemy(maxHP: 20, currentHP: 20, damageAtt: 2)
var enemyTwo = Enemy(maxHP: 40, currentHP: 40, damageAtt: 4)

func attackTarget(attacker player: Player, enemy target: Enemy) {
    var attackTAR = target
    attackTAR.currentHP -= player.damageATT
    print("Dealt \(player.damageATT) damage!")
    print("Enemy now has \(attackTAR.currentHP) health remaining")
}

attackTarget(attacker: alexRider, enemy: enemyTwo)
print(enemyTwo.currentHP)
```

Obviously, when I print the currentHP at the end of the code, its the same as it started since the scope of the variables inside the function do not pass outside. The print commands inside the function work fine to show the damage amount and remaining HP of the instance inside.

Is there something simple I am missing here? Again I know this should be something simple, but just getting started with this I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do `var attackTar = target` then using `attackTar`. Here, you create a new variable with new memory and allocate space as a different object. Simply do `target.currentHP -= player.damageATT`. Don't expect to create a new object and it reference an older object.

Comment: I tried that initially and get an error message that the Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'target' is a 'let' constant.

Comment: This is something that will be covered later in the tutorial.

Comment: Use classes instead of structs

Answer (score 1):

So, in Swift we can still pass by reference. This allows it to where our parameters are changeable because in the default case, such as yours, they are `let` variables and not mutable.

What we can do is,

```
attackTarget(attacker: alexRider, enemy: &enemyTwo)
```

as well as,

```
func attackTarget(attacker player: Player, enemy target: inout Enemy) {
```

You can see here, `inout` is similar to that of pass by reference variable in C, we just have to make it known to the Swift compiler. This will allow your variable to have variables of its own changed.